# If hasClass then fire mouseover mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a mouseover or hover function to a div when it has class `sticky`. So when the nav is sticky then `homepage-sidemenu` should get `display:none;`. `.homepage-sidemenu.sticky` should then become visible when you mouseover and invisible when mouseout.

I thought this was as simple as just adding a hover function but somehow I missing something because it doesn't do what I want. The sticky class is added with a scroll function.

A [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/meules/g4m7hgov/4/) to demonstrate what happens

So what I have is this:

```
<div id="nav">
 <ul class="menu">
  <li class="highlight"><a href="">categories</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="content">
 <div class="homepage-sidemenu">
  <ul>
   <li class="highlight">...</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>  

var fixmeTop1 = $('#nav').offset().top;
var fixmeTop = $('.homepage-sidemenu').offset().top + 100;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop1) {
        $('#nav').addClass("sticky");
    } else {
        $('#nav').removeClass("sticky");
    }
    if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {
        $('.homepage-sidemenu').addClass("sticky");
    } else {
        $('.homepage-sidemenu').removeClass("sticky");
    }

});

$('#nav.sticky .menu li.highlight').mouseover(function () {
    if ($('.homepage-sidemenu').hasClass('sticky')) {
        $('.homepage-sidemenu.sticky').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

What needs to happen is that the sidemenu disappears when the main nav is fixed/when you scroll down. When hovering the category link it should become visible.

I tried al kinds of functions (hover, mouseenter, click etc) to get this done but with no luck. It looks like something is missing when the nav is fixed.

Can somebody point me to some directions or tell me what I'm doing wrong?!

Comment: Tried just straight CSS?

Comment: Try toggling(hide/show) sidemenu when you are adding and removing sticky class in navbar

Comment: @EvanKnowles: Yes offcourse :) The problem which then occurs is that the sidemenu is first set to display:none and then somehow needs to show/hide on hover. That can't be done with pure CSS I think because the sidemenu is outside the div which is hovered.

Comment: For your info, in your case, you have to delegate event, e.g: `$(document).on('mouseover', '#nav.sticky .menu li.highlight', function() {...});` That's said, better would be to use CSS only solution. EDIT: like you said, cannot use CSS only solution without rewriting HTML markup

Answer (score 3):

You're need to use event delegation for attaching your mouseover event or just attach the event to #nav instead of #nav.sticky. You can then filter inside of the event like you're doing with homepage-sidemenu. You're trying to do the binding before #nav has the sticky class so it's not going to work.

Comment: Ok that makes sense... Do you have an example?

Comment: Tried it! The only thing that happens is that when the nav is not sticky the sidemenu still disappears when going back up! Please see my updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meules/g4m7hgov/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This: This might help you.

```
$('#nav.sticky .menu li.highlight').hover(function() {
        if ( $('.homepage-sidemenu').hasClass('sticky') ) {
            $('.homepage-sidemenu.sticky').css('display','block');
        }
    },
    function(){
        if ( $('.homepage-sidemenu').hasClass('sticky') ) {
            $('.homepage-sidemenu.sticky').css('display','none');
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: `mouseover` doesn't accept two handlers (unlike `hover` method) and anyway, there is no element `#nav.sticky` at time you are binding event (in ready handler)

Comment: But then, you cannot delegate it (in an easy way at least). You could use as selector `'#nav .menu li.highlight'` instead, but then see behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/g4m7hgov/3/

Comment: @Maverick: Your solution is a push in the right direction except that the menu dissapears when going back up! See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meules/g4m7hgov/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok thx to the help of the two answers I found a solution. Toggle css `display` isn't the right way. Better is to use `addClass` and add your css there.

So:

```
$('#nav .menu li.highlight').hover(function() {
        if ( $('.homepage-sidemenu').hasClass('sticky') ) {
           //$('.homepage-sidemenu.sticky').css('display','block');
            $('.homepage-sidemenu.sticky').addClass('active');
        }
    },
    function(){
        if ( $('.homepage-sidemenu').hasClass('sticky') ) {
            //$('.homepage-sidemenu.sticky').css('display','none');
            $('.homepage-sidemenu.sticky').removeClass('active');
        }
    }
);
```

and CSS

```
.homepage-sidemenu.sticky{
  display:none;
}
.homepage-sidemenu.sticky.active{
  display:block;
}
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meules/g4m7hgov/5/)**